# What are some great tools I should know before starting performance analysis of angularjs application?

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, watch, batarang

I need work on analysing and improving the performance of an angular application. This app handles a lot of data, tables with few thousand rows, multiple input forms in the form of custom directives. It also has a few reactJs components as integral part of application.

What all points I should keep in mind while analysing the performance, how I can improve the same and what tools I should use?

Comment: Chrome performance analysis and Batarang. Perhaps the React dev tools as well if you're mixing components to trace frequently updated components.

Comment: The common thing in any performance analysis is [code profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution?hl=en) and [timeline profiling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/analyze-runtime?hl=en) to find the bottlenecks. There are many easily googlable [in-depth] articles on performance analysis of JavaScript, and I think those are usable for any framework.